# ASP Postback deleting data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with Web Forms and I am having some trouble specifically with Drop-downs and the post back function they have. What is happening is I have multiple methods for each drop-down, so when you select a dropdown index, it will go to said method and populate the selections.

The issue is that the way to show these selections is to AutoPostBack (As far as I know) which posts back to the back-end code and runs it again. This creates issues when I try and save data to a Model such as this:

```
public class List_id_model
{
    public List<int> client_id { get; set; }
    public List<int> pro_id { get; set; }
}
```

I would have to re-instantiate the object every time I must use it, which then overwrites the data within the model. How do I prevent this from happening?

Here is my aspx code for the dropdown:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown_Project" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id" Width ="200px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDown_Project_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                        <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0" />   
                 </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void DropDown_Client_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List_id_model client_list = new List_id_model();
client_list.client_id = new List<int>();
client_list.client_id.Add(value);
}

protected void DropDown_Project_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

List_id_model client_list = new List_id_model();
client_list.pro = new List<int>();
client_list.pro_id.Add(value);
}
```

What I want to is somehow avoid re-instantiating the "List_id_model" everytime I need to add to it, since that will dump all the current data.

If you have any questions about my question I will be more than happy to get back to you tomorrow morning when I have more time to figure this out.

Comment: Your model is merely an instance of a class. You need to persist it somewhere such as ViewState, Session, a Database, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store your data at some persistent storage. In your case you should use ViewState. For example:

```
public List_id_model Model
{
  get
  {
    List_id_model model = ViewState["List_id_model"] as List_id_model;
    if (model != null)
       return model;        
    return new List_id_model();
  }
  set
  {
    ViewState["List_id_model"] = value;
  }
}

protected void DropDown_Client_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List_id_model client_list = Model;
    if (client_list.client_id == null)
       client_list.client_id = new List<int>();
    client_list.client_id.Add(value);
    Model = client_list;
}
```

This code is to demonstrate approach, I didn't try it in IDE, so sorry if you find some typos etc.

Comment: Jeez that was a quick response! I do not know much about persistent storage or ViewState for that matter. Do you have any good resources that you have used to better understand it? If not I will use some google-fu.

Comment: You may read about ViewState here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx. There are a lot articles that explain persistent storages (ViewState as well), you can google them. Also I recommend this great book - ASP.NET.3.5 Unleashed if you wanna gain deep understanding of ASP Web Forms (now available for 4.0 and 4.5 versions).